# Unity !IsDestroying() Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

In Unity I'm currently getting an error where none existed before, or if they did it didn't appear to matter.

Whenever I destroy something and go to restart the level in my game, the game freezes partway into loading and comes up with this error:

```
!IsDestroying()
UnityEngine.GameObject:AddComponent()
EggScript:OnDestroy() (at Assets/Scripts/GameScripts/EggScript.cs:85)
```

The function it's talking about:

```
void OnDestroy()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Game Paused", 1);
    transform.parent.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.AddComponent<GameOverScript>();
}
```

I've removed the PlayerPrefs call to no apparent avail but I need the other call to actually restart the level.

The other error that hasn't appeared to matter is:

```
batchDelete.reservedObjectCount >= batchDelete.objectCount
```

I'm not quite sure where I'm creating that because what I'm working on is a bit of a conglomeration of tutorials but I don't think it's relevant to this particular error.

The GameOverScript code is below (though it doesn't sound like it would be the error either):

```
void Start()
{
    GameManagerScript.Instance.pauseGame();
    //gameObject.BroadcastMessage("saveScore", null, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetString("curLevel") == "Tutorial" || PlayerPrefs.GetString("curLevel") == "Tutorial1" || PlayerPrefs.GetString("curLevel") == "Tutorial2")
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        //We're in an infinite level, so we save the score
        gameObject.BroadcastMessage("saveScore");
    }

    PauseScript.displayMenu();
    //gameObject.AddComponent<FrontmostClickCheckerScript>();

    //HighScoreManager._instance.SaveHighScore("You", (System.Int32)PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("LatestScore"));
    HighScoreManager._instance.SaveHighScore("You", GameManagerScript.Instance.getScore());
}
```

Comment: I doubt if the line `transform.parent.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.AddComponent<GameOverScript>();` is causing the problem. I suspect that the `GameObject` instance you are accessing is being "locked" during the entire destruction process, though I am not really sure about it. What happens if you comment out that line inside `OnDestroy()`?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, I can still reset the scene (just an Application.LoadLevel) with the retry button and I have the same result -- frozen game -- but without any obvious errors.

I messed around a bit more and found out it's probably my Instances. I'm following the code here: http://unitypatterns.com/singletons/ is that out of date?

Comment: You may try to attach an initially disabled `GameOverScript` to the `GameObject` you are refering to in your code. Once the game ends and `OnDestroy()` executes, enable the script by `gameOverScript.enabled = true;`. But then you code in `GameOverScript.Start` should be moved to another public function, so you may call that function from your game manager later.

Comment: Solid advice, sounds similar to what Assorted Trailmix is saying. I found that the error I was having with instances was because I didn't have my singletons under one GameObject that could stay constant. So their parent was getting destroyed and causing issues. I'll update if I can get enabling the script to work properly.

Comment: Seems to be working well again, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually believe you might be making a few mistakes here:

- transform.parent.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject.AddComponent() should be replaced with a public variable to hold that GameObject, the calling AddComponent on it, also replacing your AddComponent with enabled as was mentioned in the comments would also work.
- You're destroying an object on pause. You should post more code to give context here, but you don't want to be using OnDestroy to manage game state the way it appears that you are. You can use messaging, or references, the latter is faster, but the former is fine when you're not using it too often (read: repeatedly in OnUpdate)

I think the likeliest possibility here is the object you're calling AddComponent on might be getting Destroyed while you're trying to add the component. It'd be a very hard thing to debug here because you're climbing the hierarchy manually. Also, try removing the AddComponent altogether, it sounds like you need SetActive instead.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue, though another major problem that was a part of it was that I wasn't separating off my singletons into their own game objects that could persist through different levels/etc. I've changed so many things now I'm not sure I can track the problem down to any one root cause, but your fix was definitely a big part of it so I marked it as the answer. Thanks for the help!